# Passing variable to smarty function

Tags: smarty, smarty3, smarty2

In my PHP application, I am using Smarty for templating and use some custom functions. In the below example the function name is "text" which takes the "key" attribute. This function will get the string value based on the key

The below example works fine without issues.

```
{text key='isearch+login_name'}
```

What I am trying to do is to pass a value dynamically to the attribute. In the below code the variable $plugin will have the dynmaci value and want to be substituted.

```
{text key='isearch+$plugin_plugin'}
```

With the above code, I get the output as 'isearch+$plugin_plugin' and not the correct string value.

PHP function for the Smarty function is below.

```
function smarty_function_text($params, $smarty)
{
    $key = $params['key'];
    unset($params['key']);

    $key = explode('+', $key);

    return OW::getLanguage()->text($key[0], $key[1], $params);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `cat` filter:

```
{text key="isearch+"|cat:$plugin|cat:"_plugin"}
```

Alternatively, you can just add the string in double quotes and mark the variable part with inner quotes:

```
{text key="isearch+`$plugin`_plugin"}
```

Comment: Sorry. Neither of these worked. "_plugin" is also a string and not part of dynamic value..

Comment: Unexpected ".", expected one of: "}" , " " , ATTR

Comment: Now I am getting "Undefined Offset: 1" error showing in the Smarty function.

Comment: Edited my question to add the function code of "text".

Comment: Thanks. I get it now; I was missing `+` from the value assignment. Check the edit.

Comment: What error did you get after adding that `+`? Also if it doesn't work, add `echo $key` before calling `explode` and add here what it prints.

Comment: Ok. I got the issue.. You should be using {text key=$keyname} and not just {text key=keyname}. Please edit your answer so that I can accept it. Rest of hte code is fine.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right! Edited again. Also try the oneliner and see if it works. If it doesn't I remove it.

Comment: Both of your solutions work fine. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: Can you also check if the inner quote form works? Then I'm stopping :)

Comment: I think there was `"` missing, fixed now. But okay I give up on that one if it still doesn't work. P.S. You're welcome!

Comment: Ok great. Simplifying my answer to reflect that (the first one was an ad-hoc solution that I will remove).